# How to show all edittext error messages at once in android?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have two EditTexts and I am applying validations on them. If the validations fail, I want to show all the error messages at once. At a time, I'm getting only one error message which is fixed to the bottom `EditText` field. How to show all the `EditText` error messages at once??
I am using the following code:

```
 if(uname.matches(""))
              username.setError("Email is required");
                            
if(pwd.matches(""))
            password.setError("Password is required");
```

## my screen shot is:

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31872124/errors-with-registration-form-validation-using-seterror-in-android/31872257#31872257

Comment: use isempty() method

Comment: I have problem is in displaying two error messages not in method.Anyways thank you.

Comment: Any update on this issue ? Are you able to set both errors at once ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to setError(null) in else condition.

```
if(uname.matches(""))
              username.setError("Email is required");
else
              username.setError(null);

if(pwd.matches(""))
            password.setError("Password is required");
else
              password.setError(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

The best approach for using `setError` is to call it on fields in reverse order, so that the last call is the top-most field in the form. That way all invalid fields will be highlighted but only the top-most field will prompt the User with the error message balloon. The `setError` mechanism is designed to only show one balloon overlay at a time.

Answer (score 0):

This will help you

```
  if (TextUtils.isEmpty(username.getText().toString())) {
                    username.setError("ABC");
                }
    else(TextUtils.isEmpty(password.getText().toString())) {
                    password.setError("ABC");
                }
```