# Error Icon is not showing in all EditText fields

Tags: android

I am trying to show error icon in Edit Text and tried below code but it does not show error icon in all Edit Text Fields.

```
txtEmailAddess.requestFocus();
txtEmailAddess.setError(result.getEmailAddressMessage());
txtPassword.requestFocus();
txtPassword.setError(result.getPasswordMessage());
```

In the below screenshot, it shows error icon just in Password field. But not in Email Address field. Is that possible to show red circular icon in both fields?

[image]

**Code in Xml**

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/lblEmailAddress_login"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtEmailAddress"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/hint_email"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/lblPassword_login"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/lblEmailAddress_login">
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtPassword"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
        android:hint="@string/hint_password"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: Please add more code regarding the layout and the method you call "..setError(..)"

Comment: can you check with the xml?

Comment: Added the code. Please let me know if u need more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a `TextInputLayout`

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/text_input_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

set the error using:

```
textInputLayout.setError("Error occurs");
```

Answer (score 0):

use if else for setting error in text fields instead of requesting focus on every items of text fields

Comment: Is that possible to show error icon in all edit text fields?

Comment: yes, as in my answer you have to use if else conditions for every text fields

Answer (score 0):

Refer these two answers (They will surely resolve your issue )

[Errors with registration form Validation using setError() in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31872124/errors-with-registration-form-validation-using-seterror-in-android/31872257#31872257)

[How to show all edittext error messages at once in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31963271/how-to-show-all-edittext-error-messages-at-once-in-android)